# Cookies must be allowed skype error

Tags: internet-explorer, skype, cookies

I'm using Windows 8.1 and Skype version 7.40.0.103. It was working fine till yesterday, but now when I'm trying to login it's displaying `cookies must be allowed`

[image]

---

I've been trying to solve this issue with IE:

**First:** Accept first party and third party cookies

[image]

---

**Second:** Clear sites

[image]

---

**Third:** Reset settings

[image]

But no luck so far!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It has been resolved!
If anyone face this issue and even it's not working with all the solutions which are included in the question. Just press <kbd>Start</kbd> and search "Internet Options" and allow all cookies there.

[image]

Now run Skype again..I really don't know how it's different then IE settings :(

Hope this helps to others!